# I want to draw these figures in the link

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/galleries/588-fraction-pies-quarters
```

I can draw most of the figures in this link. But the thing i want to know is how to shade a region as in the figures 3,4,5,6.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted so many times? Seems perfectly reasonable to me. Shaheryar simply wants to know how to fill a shape with a horizontal hatching pattern.

Comment: @JohnWickerson Every now and then we get excited and overvote. It would even out in the long run.

Comment: This question would be substantially improved by showing us how you draw at least of the the figures.  We would then know which graphics package you are working with.

Answer (score 14):

I think this covers all the required use-cases:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{4}
\tikzset{wedges/.pic={
  \pgfmathdectobase\n{#1}{2}\pgfmathtodigitlist{\l}{\n}%
  \foreach \p [count=\j from 0] in \l
    \path [rotate=-\j*90-90, wedge \p/.try] 
      (0:0) -- (0:.5) arc (0:90:.5) -- cycle;
}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={xc(\i)=1.5*mod(\i,4);yc(\i)=-1.5*int(\i/4);}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,15}
  \path [wedge 0/.style={draw=none}, wedge 1/.style={draw}]
    (xc \i, yc \i) pic {wedges=\i};

\foreach \i in {0,...,15}
  \path [wedge 0/.style={draw}, wedge 1/.style={draw, shift=(45:1/4)}]
      (6.25+xc \i, yc \i) pic {wedges=\i};

\foreach \i in {0,...,15}
  \path [wedge 0/.style={draw}, wedge 1/.style={draw, pattern=north west lines}]
      (xc \i, -6.25+yc \i) pic {wedges=\i};

\foreach \i in {0,...,15}
  \path [wedge 0/.style={fill=black!25}, wedge 1/.style={fill=black!75}]
     (6.25+xc \i,-6.25+yc \i) pic {wedges=\i};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

% first pie chart
\def\sizeA{2}
% second pie chart
\def\sizeB{1.5}
\def\replacement{0.3}
\pstFPadd\maximum{\sizeB}{\replacement}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\sizeA,-\sizeA)(\sizeA,\sizeA)
  \pswedge{\sizeA}{0}{90}                        % 1st quadrant
  \pswedge[fillstyle = hlines]{\sizeA}{90}{180}  % 2nd quadrant
  \pswedge{\sizeA}{180}{270}                     % 3rd quadrant
  \pswedge[fillstyle = hlines]{\sizeA}{270}{360} % 4th quadrant
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}(-\sizeB,-\sizeB)(\maximum,\maximum)
  \rput(\replacement,\replacement){\pswedge{\sizeB}{0}{90}}
  \pswedge{\sizeB}{90}{180}
  \pswedge{\sizeB}{180}{270}
  \pswedge{\sizeB}{270}{360}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]